# Flutter Icon showing Icons that were different than specified

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

When I tell the icon to be on one type it shows something completely different.

```
  Icon(
     Icons.ac_unit
       ),
```

[image]

It was supposed to be an ac unit but it's this instead. This even affects included

widgets like the calendar widget. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` & `flutter pub cache repair` to see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: That made the problem worse now all the icons are Question Marks